# How to wire multiple ir photodiodes on one arduino pin?

Tags: arduino, infrared, photodiode

I'd like to use 50  ir photodiodes. 
But, I'm not sure about it because I want it to be read only on one analog pin of an arduino.

My idea is to wire parallel like in this picture.

But, I'm just not sure if all photodiodes will work if I wire like this...

So, is my schematic right or wrong? 
If it is OK, what value should I use for the resistors?

Or do I need another component to connect all the photodiodes to one pin on an arduino?

Thanks[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Passerby i want it as a detector

Comment: I don't expect this to work or be able to do anything useful. All photodiodes are forward biased so you would just get a voltage of around 0.7 V independent of any IR. Photodiodes are normally operated in reverse bias.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Sorry im forgot to reversed biase it, so the position of photodiode is opposite, but would that work if i paralel it??

Comment: OK, yes that could work. But what are you trying to detect ? Depending on the type of IR light you want to detect, this can work or not. For slow changing IR (sunlight) it could work, for IR remote signals it will not (this setup will be too slow).

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thanks, nice to hear that it will work,i'll design it into circle, i want to detect insect that move across it

Comment: @FakeMoustache i didn't understand with slow changing.. but i need it to fast read... how? what i need to make it read fastly?

Comment: This setup will be slow because you put 50 diodes in parallel. Each diode is also a small capacitance in parallel with the diode so you have 50 capacitors in parallel with the diodes. The diodes only give a small current change when the IR changes, this current change will "disappear" in the 50 small capacitors you have. You should use a transimpedance amplifier to eliminate the influence of the capacitances: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier

Comment: @FakeMoustache hmm, so i should wire every photodiode with transimpedance that you refered.. ok i'll try it thanks very muchh i hope i can find the ic needed for transimpedance amplifier in my country

Comment: I would try with one diode and a transimpedance amplifier and check  if that works for what you need. Then try 5 diodes in parallel and one TI amplifier and see if that is OK as well. Take it step by step ! For the IC: almost any decent Opamp should be usable, for example TL071, MCP601 etc. A "general purpose opamp" but check that the supply voltage is what you can use. Some opamps need +15 and -15 V supplies.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - I think you're confusing him. His idea of "fast" is detecting a bug walking over the diodes. Call it 10 to 100 millisecond response. I doubt that's your idea of fast. And I doubt that diode capacitance will be a problem.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yeah, i mean "fast" for sensitivity of whole photodiode to detect.. how?

Comment: @rezhart  Can you use phototransistors instead of photodiodes?  Is the insect going to reflect light to detectors, or interrupt light?  If you detect an insect, but can't detect which photodiode, is that good enough for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @NickAlexeev sadly i have already bought a whole photodiode so ill use photodiode instead of phototransistor.. my idea is insect going to reflect, but if it fail, i'll use it to interrupt light since i use a lamp too to trap it

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that doing it the simple way simply will not work. Let's say that your diodes are drawing 1 mA each. With 50 in parallel, that will be a total of 50 mA. Assuming a resistor of about 50 ohms, your nominal voltage will be $$V= 5 - iR = 5 - .05\times 50 = 5 - 2.5 = 2.5 \text{ volts} $$ and if a bug blocks all of the light to one diode the current will drop by 1 mA, and the voltage will increase by $$\Delta V = .001\times 50 = 50\text{ millivolts} $$ While this is detectable with an Arduino, it overlooks something important. If the overall illumination level changes by 2%, the current will also change by 1 mA, and the voltage change will be impossible to distinguish from a bug.

What you need to do is to sample each diode in series, and fast enough not to miss a bug, and at your apparent level of knowledge I haven't the faintest idea how to do that.

Sorry.

Comment: hmm, i have idea not to use 1 pin but 5 analog pin, how if i paralel it into 10 and wiring into 5 pin analog or series it into 10 and wiring into 5 pin? will it work? and which better series or paralel wiring for this case?

Comment: sorry, i think photodiode cant series wiring :(